# CPU Upgrade to Phenom II X6

Tags: cpu, bios, motherboard, compatibility, amd-phenom

I have an old desktop HP DC5850 SFF with a CPU Phenom II X4 B97 and I'm considering to upgrade it.
Unfortunately, the HP Manual is very old (October 2008) and have not been updated since. For example, even my current CPU and its entire Phenom II family are not covered in the support list. Therefore, using the CPU support list available in the HP manual won't help much:

> ###### 2.3.1 AMD Processor Support
>
> The models covered in this guide are designed to support the following processor types:
>
> - AMD Phenom X4 Quad-Core with HyperTransport Technology
> - AMD Phenom X3 Triple-Core with HyperTransport Technology
> - AMD Athlon X2 Dual-Core with HyperTransport Technology
> - AMD Athlon 64 Single-Core with HyperTransport Technology
> - AMD Sempron with HyperTransport Technology
>
> *Source: [Technical Reference Guide: HP Compaq dc5850 Series Business Desktop Computers](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01602850.pdf)*

Searching over the net, I've noticed that there are other CPUs very similar to mine but with better performance:

| Model | Clock speed | Turbo speed | TDP | Socket | Release Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Phenom II X4 B97 | 3.2 GHz | - | 95 W | AM3 | May 11, 2010 |
| Phenom II X6 1065T | 2.9 GHz | 3.4 GHz | 95 W | AM3 | Dec 07, 2010 |

*Source: [Wikipedia: List of AMD Phenom processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_Phenom_processors)*

Notice the following:

- Both CPUs have the same 95W TDP, therefore this should not be an issue.
- Both CPUs have the same AM3 socket, therefore this should not be an issue.
  Note: Although the motherboard is AM2+, "As AM3 processors also support DDR2, they are backwards-compatible with Socket AM2/AM2+, contingent upon a BIOS update" — [Wikipedia: Socket AM3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_AM3#Compatibility)
- Both CPUs were released considerably sooner than the BIOS (nov 15, 2011), therefore it is possible that the BIOS supports it.

Also, according to the HP Manual, this motherboard uses an AMD 780V chipset which seems to support the Phenom II X6 1065T CPU (*source: [CPU-Upgrade: AMD 780V chipset processor support](https://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-AMD_(chipsets)/780V.html)*).

Therefore, based on all the aforementioned reasoning, it seems that **there is hope that this system supports Phenom II X6 CPU**.

###### Question

Is it possible to upgrade this system to a Phenom II X6 CPU?

---

#### Additional Info

###### HP Manual

*Source: [Technical Reference Guide: HP Compaq dc5850 Series Business Desktop Computers](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01602850.pdf)*

- The processor mounts in a zero-insertion-force (ZIF) AMD **AM2+ socket**.
- These systems can only support a processor with a maximum power consumption (also known as thermal design power (TDP)) of **95 watts**.
- The **AMD 780V chipset** consists of a RS780C north bridge and an SB700 south bridge.

###### Bios

```
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.5 present.

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    Version: 786F6 v03.14
    Release Date: 11/15/2011
  [...]
    BIOS Revision: 3.14
  [...]
```

###### Motherboard

```
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.5 present.

Handle 0x0003, DMI type 2, 8 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
    Product Name: 3029h
    Version: Not Specified
    [...]
```

Comment: Borderline, might be better asked on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Don't you think `retrocomputing` is too ancient for a Phenom?

Comment: @spikey_richie Just for the records: There is no AMD tag in `retrocomputing`, while here there is even an AMD-PHENOM tag. Mind to reconcile?

Comment: @JeronBaffom - just because an inexperienced user created a tag doesn’t mean it should exist